# Can not indentify accounts

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to get balance of accounts and when running `bitcoin-cli listaccounts` I am getting the data look like this

```
{
  "":0.81234545
}
```

I wanted to know what is the `""` and `0.81234545` and where my real addresses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note: The accounts feature is being deprecated from the codebase. Accounts are groupings of addresses, constructed by the wallet software.

You may find that the `listunspent` or `listreceivedbyaddress` commands are more useful for you.

> I wanted to know what is the `""` and `0.81234545` and where my real addresses

`""` is the default name of an account

`0.81234545` is the balance of your wallet, in BTC.

Comment: I generated  more than 20 accounts. Waht do you mean saying default name of an account ?

Comment: Note that an account is not an address. An account is a group of addresses made by your wallet. For convenience, you can name the accounts you create. If you do not specify an account name, the default name is an empty string, `""`.

Comment: So but when I want to get balance of account , I am getting 0.0000 but bitcoin explorer site shows that balance of account is 0.12345667. Why ? )

Comment: In `bitcoind`, an **account** is different than an **address**. A bitcoin explorer site would not show you an account, it would show you an address. To show you one of your 'accounts', the explorer site would need to know which group of addresses to include, but only your wallet will know that info. Trying to compare the output of `bitcoin-cli listaccounts` with a block explorer site will not work in almost every case.